# Is it possible to draw dates per line?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing a particular issue with D3.js. I currently have a dataset similar to:

```
[
    { title: 'First title', dates: [ /* a lot of dates */ ] },
    { title: 'Second title', dates: [ /* a lot of dates */ ] },
    // ...
]
```

I want to draw a container per line, and then in each container, to draw some `drops`, each one corresponding to a date.

For drawing line containers, I have the following code:

```
const dropLines = svg.selectAll('.drops').data(data, d => d.title);

dropLines.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', (d, idx) => `translate(10, ${scales.y(idx)})`)
    .attr('fill', configuration.eventLineColor)
    .classed('drops', true);

dropLines.exit().remove();
```

It works well and I got all my line containers.

However, how can I draw drops for my dates? I tried something like:

```
const drop = data => {
    console.log(data);
};

dropLines.enter()
    // ...
    .each(drop);
```

But I got the whole data set (with titles) in my `console.log`. I would expect to get only the current selected element data.

Is it possible to draw my dates per line? If so, how can I retrieve only current data, and current selection (the current line container)?

Comment: @isherwood: I agree for the tag edition, but not the title. This is by far less meaningful.

Comment: Your original question title ("entering a sub-selection in an enter") was very unclear. Feel free to edit as you see fit. No need to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subselection. I usually use `.each` for this:

```
// Note: Not .enter(), you've already handled that
dropLines.each(function(drop) {
    // Now a new selection
    var date = d3.select(this).selectAll('.date').data(drop.dates);

    // "date" is now bound to the array of dates, proceed as usual
    date.enter().append(
        // ... etc
    )
});
```